# N-bodies simulation with parallel processing

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I am trying to create an N-bodies simulation in a 100lyx100ly galaxy in C language using the MPI library. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define G 6.674e-11  // Gravitational constant
#define m 2e30       // Body mass

typedef struct {
    double x, y; //Positions
    double vx, vy; //Velocity
}Body;

void update_velocity (Body* bodies, int num_bodies, int rank, int size) {
    int i, j;
    double fx, fy, dx, dy, dist, dist_cubed, theta;
    double *forces = (double *) malloc(num_bodies * sizeof(double));
    
    memset(forces, 0, num_bodies * sizeof(double));
    
    for (i=0; i < num_bodies * 2; i++){
        forces[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = rank; i < num_bodies; i += size) {    //Utilization of parallel processing power
        fx = fy = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < num_bodies; j++) {     //update body [i] compared to all other bodies in the system
            if (i != j) {
                dx = bodies[j].x - bodies[i].x;
                dy = bodies[j].y - bodies[i].y;
                dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                dist_cubed = dist * dist;
                // Calculate theta using tan(dx/dy)
                theta = atan(dx / dy);
                theta = theta * 180 / M_PI;
                fx += G * m * m * cos(theta) / dist_cubed;    //The sum of the forces acting on a body in the x direction
                fy += G * m * m * sin(theta) / dist_cubed;    //The sum of the forces acting on a body in the y direction
            }
        }
        forces[i] = fx;
        forces[i + num_bodies] = fy;

        // Update acceleration
        bodies[i].vx += forces[i] / m;
        bodies[i].vy += forces[i + num_bodies] / m;
    }   
    
    // Reduce all the local forces to get the total forces on each process  
    MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, bodies, num_bodies * 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    free(forces);    
}

void update_position(Body* bodies, int num_bodies) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_bodies; i++) {
        bodies[i].x += bodies[i].vx;
        bodies[i].y += bodies[i].vy;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int rank, size, num_bodies, timesteps, i, j;
    int namelen;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    fprintf(stderr,"Process %d on %s\n",rank,processor_name);
    fflush(stderr);

    num_bodies = 992;  // Number of bodies
    timesteps = 100;  // Number of time steps
    
    Body* bodies = NULL;

    if (rank == 0) {

        // Generate initial random positions and velocities for bodies
        bodies = (Body *) malloc(num_bodies * sizeof(Body));

        for (i = 0; i < num_bodies; i++) {
            bodies[i].x = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * 100.0;  //generate values between 0 to 100
            bodies[i].y = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * 100.0;
            bodies[i].vx = 0.0;  // Set initial velocity in x direction to zero
            bodies[i].vy = 0.0;  // Set initial velocity in y direction to zero
        }
        // Broadcast the updated positions to other processes
        MPI_Bcast(bodies, num_bodies * sizeof(Body), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // Simulation loop
    for (i = 0; i < timesteps; i++) {
        update_velocity(bodies, num_bodies, rank, size);
        update_position(bodies, num_bodies);

        if (rank == 0) {
            // Print or process the updated positions as needed
            printf("Positions after time step %d:\n", i+1);
            for (j = 0; j < num_bodies; j++) {
                printf("Body %d: x = %.2f, y = %.2f\n", j+1, bodies[j].x, bodies[j].y);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    free(bodies);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

When trying to run with 2/4/6/8 processes I get a signal 11 error.
I tried initialize all the elements of the forces array to 0 שnd still every time I get the same error.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: It might help to include any details on the exact error you're seeing including full error message and any useful pieces of a trace.  Also please discuss steps that you've tried to debug it.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask